# What is the most efficient way to sort a collection of items into buckets?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, bucket

I have an array of arbitrary hashes, with an element of the hash an integer (call it 'id'). I want to sort these hashes into a number of buckets (constant over the array), where each bucket is an arbitrary range of 'ids' (e.g. 1-10, 15-20, 20-30). What is the best sorting strategy to do this? Is it possible to do without a nested loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the number of buckets is small, you are probably better off with the nested loops.  The outer loop over the hashes, and the inner over the buckets.  `O(n*m)`.

If the number of hashes, and the number of buckets are large, you can:

```
hashes = sort(hashes)
buckets = sort(buckets) # sort by lower-bound of bucket
i = 0

foreach (hash in hashes) {
  while (buckets[i].lower_bound > hash) {
    i = i + 1
  }
  bucket[i].add(hash)
}
```

The basically loops through the hashes adding them to the current bucket and advancing to the next bucket when needed. O(n*log(n) + m*log(m))

Answer (score 1):

If the hashes are good quality, they will exhibit an even distribution, so you can use evenly-distributed buckets to partition the collection in a single pass.

If you also want the hashes sorted within the buckets, use a normal sorting algorithm after everything is in buckets. This would be an unusual use of hashes, however. (If you aren't trying to sort within buckets, then the word "sort" is a misnomer. What you really wanted was partitioning.)

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention a language/platform, but for efficient in terms of keystrokes (C#):

```
        var histogram = new[] { 0, 10, 15, 20, 30, 40 };
        var values = new[] { 12, 14, 5, 6, 7, 1, 34, 26, 17 };
        var bars = values.GroupBy(v => histogram.First(b => v < b));
```